# Why is this animation not moving? Matplotlib animation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, animation

I am trying to plot an animation of the time evolution of a multiple top hat functions with different values of x_0 and alpha("a" in the code). It looks like it is plotting correctly, but it doesn't actually animate. I've tried varying frame_num, the frames and the interval. I've also tried calling the f_xtsqrd function before defining the line in the animation function, and testing the f_xtsqrd function to see if it actually changes with t, which it does. The labels are just placeholders at the moment. I know that the first chunk of code which I've lined off with ---- works, but the rest I'm not sure. I'm baffled as to what I've done wrong here, any help would be much appreciated.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from IPython import display

def energy_eigen_odd(x,n,t=0): # Even meaning even n
  energy=n**2*np.pi**2/2
  eigen = np.sqrt(2)*np.cos(np.pi*n*x)*np.cos(energy*t)
  return eigen,energy

def energy_eigen_even(x,n,t=0):
  energy=n**2*np.pi**2/2
  eigen = np.sqrt(2)*np.sin(np.pi*n*x)*np.cos(energy*t)
  return eigen,energy

def energy_eigen_odd_image(x,n,t=0): # Even meaning even n
  energy=n**2*np.pi**2/2
  eigen = np.sqrt(2)*np.cos(np.pi*n*x)*np.sin(energy*t)
  return eigen,energy

def energy_eigen_even_image(x,n,t=0):
  energy=n**2*np.pi**2/2
  eigen = np.sqrt(2)*np.sin(np.pi*n*x)*np.sin(energy*t)
  return eigen,energy

def fn_odd(n,alpha,x_0): # Definining functions for fn for if it's being applied to odd or even psi.

  return np.sqrt(8/alpha)*(1/(n*np.pi))*np.cos((n*np.pi*x_0))*np.sin((n*np.pi*alpha)/2)

def fn_even(n,alpha,x_0):

  return np.sqrt(8/alpha)*(1/(n*np.pi))*np.sin((n*np.pi*x_0))*np.sin((n*np.pi*alpha)/2)
alpha=0.5
x_0=0.5
x=np.linspace(-1,1,1000)
def f_xt(x,n,x_0,alpha,t=0):
  sum_real=0
  sum_imag=0

  for i in range(1,n):
      
      if i % 2 == 0:# Determining the function is even
        sum_real += fn_even(i,alpha,x_0)*energy_eigen_even(x,i)[0]
        sum_imag += fn_even(i,alpha,x_0)*energy_eigen_even_image(x,i)[0]


      if i % 2 == 1: # Determining the function is odd
        sum_real += fn_odd(i,alpha,x_0)*energy_eigen_odd(x,i)[0]
        sum_imag += fn_odd(i,alpha,x_0)*energy_eigen_odd_image(x,i)[0]

  return sum_real, sum_imag
def f_xtsqrd(x,n,x_0,alpha,t=0):
  x,y=f_xt(x,n,x_0,alpha)
  return x**2 + y**2

----------------------------------------------------------------------------

fig=plt.figure()
ax=plt.axes()
x_01=-0.1
x_02=0.2
x_03=0.4
a1=0.8
a2=0.5
a3=0.2
line1, = ax.plot([],[],label=f'Alpha={a1}, x_0={x_01}')#Making empty lines to fill later.
line2, = ax.plot([],[],label=f'Alpha={a2}, x_0={x_02}')
line3, = ax.plot([],[],label=f'Alpha={a3}, x_0={x_03}')

x=np.linspace(-0.5,0.5,1000)
plt.xlabel('Time(Units)')
plt.ylabel('Values of data')
ax.legend(loc='upper right')#Defining where the legend is so it doesn't bounce around during the animation

# Setting axes so they don't move from frame to frame
ax.set_xlim(-0.5,0.5)
ax.set_ylim(0,10)

def animate(frame_num): # Defining the animation function
    
    n=50
    line1.set_data(x,f_xtsqrd(x,n,x_01,a1,t=0.1*frame_num))
    line2.set_data(x,f_xtsqrd(x,n,x_02,a2,t=0.1*frame_num))
    line3.set_data(x,f_xtsqrd(x,n,x_03,a3,t=0.1*frame_num))
 
    return line1,line2,line3

anim=FuncAnimation(fig,animate,frames=200, interval=10) #Setting the animation function to animate the figure, with 200 frames.

#The code needed to make the animation display
video = anim.to_html5_video()
html = display.HTML(video)
display.display(html)
plt.close()
```

Comment: Please include the the function `f_xtsqrd` otherwise this isn't a reproducible example because other people can't run your code.

Comment: I have now done that, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the code stops passing the `t` variable made from `frame_num` to the relevant functions. (Also since you defined a default value `t=0` in these functions, no error is shown as a result of this.) See the modified functions below that make the animation run properly:

```
def f_xt(x, n, x_0, alpha, t=0):
    sum_real = 0
    sum_imag = 0

    for i in range(1, n):

        if i % 2 == 0:  # Determining the function is even
            sum_real += fn_even(i, alpha, x_0) * energy_eigen_even(x, i, t)[0]
            sum_imag += fn_even(i, alpha, x_0) * energy_eigen_even_image(x, i, t)[0]

        if i % 2 == 1:  # Determining the function is odd
            sum_real += fn_odd(i, alpha, x_0) * energy_eigen_odd(x, i, t)[0]
            sum_imag += fn_odd(i, alpha, x_0) * energy_eigen_odd_image(x, i, t)[0]

    return sum_real, sum_imag


def f_xtsqrd(x, n, x_0, alpha, t=0):
    x, y = f_xt(x, n, x_0, alpha, t)
    return x ** 2 + y ** 2
```